# How can I recreate a model with multiple view angles?

Tags: modeling, mesh, image, geometry, topology

[image: 3 angles of a head model with "wireframe"]

I have a image of a head from 3d.sk that shows 3 angles with the polygon faces easily visible. I had the idea to set up multiple cameras and try to eyeball the placement of the vertices but it's always off, whats the best way to figure out how to combine the images and see what the fov perspective is?

dec 10 - 2022:
I can use blender tracking to make the model but I'm still open for any other solutions.

Comment: Have you tried addon Face Builder (Keen Tools) ...

Comment: Do you just want to recreate this model in particular? The face or the topology (*"...try to eyeball the placement of the vertices... "*) or both? Just in generally create head models?

Comment: I already used up the free trial for face builder and I don't like it. I want to accurately recreate the 3d head model and use the same technique for simuler images, I don't know how to reply to comments so I help they see this one...